# Polymorphic - Create inserting record and following up with blank record

Tags: laravel, eloquent, entity-relationship

I've setup a Polymorphic Relationship on my model for this, I've had to create matching fields to the table that the morph refers to.

So I've created a

**Translation Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Translation extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'translations';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'text_line1', 'text_line2', 'quote', 'language', 'content', 'translationable_type','translationable_id', 'content'];

    use SoftDeletes;

    public function translationable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

This is the Polymorph, Then in a seperate model - "Slides"

I've created this:

**Slide Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Slide extends Model
{
    /**
     * Slide table
     */
    protected $table = 'slides';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function translations()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Translation', 'translationable', 'translations', '', 'translationable_id');
    }

}
```

Then in a controller, I've made a test script...

```
$slide = Slide::find(16);

        $translations = array(
            'text_line1'            => $slide->text_line1,
            'text_line2'            => $slide->text_line2,
            'language'              => 'fr',
            'translationable_id'    => $slide->id,
            'translationable_type'  => 'App\Slide'
        );

        $slide->translations()->create($translations);
```

When I run this, It creates the record, But also creates another record that is totally blank other than referencing the *translationable_id* and *translationable_type*

Anyone know why it would do this?

Cheers.

Comment: Could you try changing the empty string to null in your `morphToMany` declaration: `'translations', null`. Or try it with `$this->morphToMany('App\Models\Translation', 'translationable');` since your using the laravel naming convention so laravel can generate those values itself.

Comment: Hi @Remul unfortunatley still the same...

return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Translation', 'translationable', 'translations', null, 'translationable_id');

Comment: Hi @Remul appreciate your help on this one, managed to find a solution :

return $this->morphMany(Translation::class, 'translationable');

Comment: Right, your using a one-to-many relation and not a many-to-many relation so that makes sense.

Comment: As a sidenote: when creating the translation you can remove `translationable_id` and `translationable_type ` from the array that you are passing to `$slide->translations()->create()`, laravel will fill those values by itself.